# Laravel session cookies with API token

Tags: php, laravel, api, hybrid-mobile-app, laravel-passport

We have a hybrid application for phone. Some pages are implemented in app and the other ones we show like web pages.
So i could say it's browser with several offline pages.

Login function are implemented in browser exactly. And at the same time user should be authorised in browser too. 
So...The only logical solution for me it's to get token via API and then set session cookies in inner browser.

I think most secured way it's send post request inside browser with token. But is there any public function to "parse" this token?

Or other way - send api request to get cookies directly. There is also no function to get session cookies. Only for xsrf-token.

Or is there any way to use api token like session for regular routes?

Answer (score 0):

You may give `Laravel Passport` a try. It's an official laravel package, you can see the details in their docs.

Comment: Am i already use this. The question is - how i can detect user by getting token in post request for example? If i already have this token then how can i set session cookies by using token?

Comment: Pass the token you obtained from `Passport` then in your function you may access the authenticated using `Auth::user()`. Then you can login a `User` instance using `Auth::login($user)`

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. Where i can find `$user` by using token? How to detect user by token in regular routes

Comment: When you guard your routes using an `auth:api` middleware, you can access the authenticated user by just calling `Auth::user()`. Given that you are using `Passport`